# How to clone FormattedText?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have FormattedText called "oldf" that been retrieved from a function.

```
FormattedText oldf = GetFormattedText();
```

I want to use the oldf to create newf that is exact the same besides the text.

I tried something like that :

```
    FormattedText newf = new FormattedText("myNewText",oldf.CultureInfo,oldf.FlowDirection,oldf.TypeFace,
        oldf.EmSize, oldf.Foreground);
```

But with no success.

Comment: @agent-j  - please try to do what i've tried and you'll see that it is not possible.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to misuse the `FormattedText`.  A FormattedText doesn't necessarily have just one ForegroundBrush, for example.  Hence the `SetForegroundBrush(Brush foregroundBrush, int startIndex, int count);`  If you want to re-use the object, why not just set the `Text` property?

Answer (score 0):

That values are the parameters that are passed in the constructor, but they are not properties which can be found in the class: [FormattedText Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.FormattedText(v=vs.100).aspx)

If you want to repeat the values, you need to store them elsewhere

(The Text property is readonly)